# Error on branch creation: "warning: refname 'master' is ambiguous."

Tags: git, git-branch

I've had simple project being managed in a Git repository. To date I haven't intentionally created any branches, but when I tried to create my first today using

```
$ git branch mybranch
```

I see this error:

```
warning: refname 'master' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'master'.
```

Digging deeper:

```
$ git branch -a          
* master
remotes/master/HEAD -> master/master
remotes/master/master
```

Is this normal to see in Git? Have I cloned my repository incorrectly? What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Comment: It does appear that you did something weird when cloning. To clone correctly, use `git clone [url] [destination path]`. For more diagnostic help, post what you get when you run `git config -l`

Comment: Thanks mark, I get:

   core.repositoryformatversion=0
   core.filemode=true
   core.bare=false
   core.logallrefupdates=true
   core.ignorecase=true
   remote.master.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/master/*
   remote.master.url=git@github.com:###/###.git
   branch.master.remote=master
   branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems it's ambiguous because your remote name and branch name are both `master`. You can try renaming the remote to the more conventional `origin` by running

```
git remote rename master origin
```

Answer (score 6):

The rules for how revision specifications are interpreted are given in [*gitrevisions(7)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) (referenced from [*git(1)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html), among other bits of documentation).

In short, `master` matches two patterns when applied to the refs in your repository: a local branch (`refs/heads/<name>`) and the default remote-tracking branch of a remote (`refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD`).

These can be disambiguated by using `heads/master` for the local branch and `master/HEAD` (or `master/master` in your case) for the remote-tracking branch.

As [Andrew Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280212/git-error-on-branch-creation-warning-refname-master-is-ambiguous/5280248#5280248) mentions, you might want to rename your remote to avoid having to disambiguate in the first place.

Comment: +1 for referencing the documentation where this is explained.  I wish git didn't try `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD` - it only creates confusion for people who aren't quite sure what remotes and branches are, with very little benefit for anyone who does understand the difference...

Answer (score 0):

In my case HEAD branch was ambiguous and solved by deleting local branch using

```
git branch -d HEAD
```

may need to push changes before not to lose changes