# Refname 'master' is ambiguous

Tags: git

I've looked at all of the other ambiguous refname questions and none of them seem to help. Why am I getting this warning?

```
$ git checkout master
warning: refname 'master' is ambiguous.
$ git show-ref master
eef61c00da690f093063ac5a728e22fd21648104 refs/heads/master
$ git branch -a
  checkers
  exercises
* master
$ git remote -v
$
```

Comment: [Follow the link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280212/git-error-on-branch-creation-warning-refname-master-is-ambiguous)

Comment: As stated in my question, there is only one master branch and no remotes for this repo. The user in the question you linked to had a problem with a remote and a branch having the same name.

Comment: Do you have a tag named "master"?

Comment: A method of preventing this is to develop a convention in your codebase/org that ensures you never create overlapping refs. I use the following: For non-origin local branches use: `local-<remote>/master`. For release branches and tags, use something like `release/1.x.x` for release branches (i.e. git flow feature freeze) and `release-tag/1.1.0` for tagging deployed/released code, and to disallow naming a branch `release`, `release-tag` or the name of an origin.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

TL;DR: save and delete the tag, as [Ashutosh Jindal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325742/ashutosh-jindal) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224773/git-refname-master-is-ambiguous/12225704?noredirect=1#comment28041784_12225704) (see "[Rename a tag in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/6309)"):

```
git tag tag-master master
git tag -d master
```

---

Original answer:

Most of the sources I see (like [this FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/GitFAQ#I_get_an_ambiguous_warning_when_checking_out_a_branch)) point to the same cause:

> When you try to checkout a local branch, you get a

```
warning: refname 'branch-name' is ambiguous
```

> **This can happen if you've created a local branch with the same name as a remote tag**.
>   Git should be checking out your local branch, but instead it's trying to checkout the tag, and it gets confused.
>
> The initial import of several trees were problematic, since they contained identically named branches and tags. We have since addressed a lot of these issues, by **[renaming away the tags](http://www.mono-project.com/GitFAQ/fixup-tags.sh)**.

In your case, you don't have a remote, but local tags named like your branch could be enough.

The ambiguity is specified in **[gitrevision](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)**

#### `<refname>`, e.g. `master`, `heads/master`, `refs/heads/master`

> A symbolic ref name. E.g. `master` typically means the commit object referenced by `refs/heads/master`.
>   **If you happen to have both `heads/master` and `tags/master`, you can explicitly say `heads/master`** to tell git which one you mean.
>   When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
>
> - otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> - otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> - otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> - otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> - otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

So check where `master` can be found in your repo.

And `git checkout heads/master` would always work.
Warning: by default, this would checkout the branch in a [DETACHED HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309). See "[Why does `git checkout` with explicit '`refs/heads/branch`' give detached HEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)".

To avoid that, and still use an unambiguous ref, type:

```
git checkout -B master heads/master
```

Comment: The search order for refs was helpful. `$GIT_DIR/master` did exist for some reason (no idea what it was pointing to or how it was created). Removing it fixed the warning.

Comment: @Max, this was exactly my problem -- something made a .git/master file (whose contents was a hash, pointing at what the master *used to be* several revs ago) and renaming it fixed the warnings.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! So my fix was `git tag tag-master master ; git tag -d master` (This was also helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028649/rename-a-tag-in-git)

Comment: @AshutoshJindal Excellent! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: But what if that tag belonged to a release that we've already deployed? Deleting the tag would delete the release. I don't want that!

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation "release" is not a Git notion, but a GitHub or GitLab one. The OP is only about Git. You can wrap those commands in a script which will query your remote Git repositories hosting service and check if the deleted tag is part of a release (for example, for GitHub, with [`gh release view [tag]`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_view)). But that is out of scope for this question/answer.

Answer (score 44):

Although this doesn't apply to the OP's situation, I got myself a `refname is ambiguous` warning after accidentally doing a `git branch origin/branch` instead of a `git checkout origin/branch`. This created a local branch named `origin/branch`, which made it ambiguous with the remote branch. Solving the problem was as simple as `git branch -D origin/branch` (safe because `-D` operates on local branches).

Comment: This has happened to me more than once, the most frustrating and baffling symptom when I delete the `master` branch, yet it still shows up when doing `git rev-parse master`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer explained me what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 25):

This just happened to me.  I somehow had a file .git/master containing a sha.  Not sure how that got there, but when I deleted it, the error went away.  If you read the accepted answer carefully, this is "expected behavior" but you won't see that .git/master if you do e.g. git show-ref master because it follows slightly different rules.

Comment: It is caused when you forget the "refs/heads" part of the update-ref command (well for me it was anyway).  See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073062/git-warning-refname-master-is-ambiguous/16302266#16302266

Comment: This was my issue. `git checkout master` loaded the branch correctly, `git diff master staging` used the ancient reference, which got confusing.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Took me way too long to realize, I finally noticed it after running `find .git -iname master`

Comment: Apparently such files are called [pseudoref](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pseudoref) — like .git/FETCH_HEAD etc.  It's annoying that `update-ref foo/bar` [happily creates them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006054/why-does-git-update-ref-accepts-non-refs-references) yet `update-ref -d foo/bar` will refuse to delete "bad name", need `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

This message will appear as well if you had erroneously configured two remote servers with the same name which gives the ambiguity.

Check your `.git/config` file. If you have more than one remote repo configured with the same:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

you should change one of them to a different name, eg.:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/another_repo/*`