# Why does git update-ref accepts non /refs references?

Tags: git, reference

While commands like "git log" will happily accept different expressions for the same ref, e.g.

```
refs/heads/master
heads/master
master
```

this is not true for "git update-ref". For example

```
git update-ref master HEAD^
```

is not the same as

```
git update-ref refs/heads/master HEAD^
```

The first command creates a new ref .git/master (and in turn introduces an ambiguity regarding refs/heads/master). Only the second command really updates master's head. (.git/refs/heads/master)

Why does git update-ref accepts references without "refs/" prefix? Shouldn't there be at least a warning or a command line option to force creation of such references?

It took me quite a long time to figure out why

```
git update-ref master HEAD^
```

did not work as expected.

Comment: Consider that you really want to create/update `.git/master`. What command would you use in that case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### tl;dr

The main reason why `git log` and `git update-ref` behave differently is because `git-log` is a *high-level* command – and therefore designed to be user-friendly – while `git-update-ref` is a *low-level* command meant to be used in scripts.

### Porcelain vs. Plumbing

In Git parlance, high-level commands are referred to as [*porcelain*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain#_plumbing_porcelain) while low-level ones are collectively called [*plumbing*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Commands-Plumbing-Commands).

Porcelain commands are meant to be used *interactively* by humans and therefore expose familiar high-level concepts such as [*symbolic references*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).
Plumbing commands, on the other hand, are meant to be used *programmatically* – usually in scripts – and allow to directly manipulate Git's internal file system structures.

### git-update-ref

While `git-log` is able to resolve *references*, `git-update-ref` – it being a plumbing command – interprets [the first argument](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/update-ref.c#L43-L73) as either a *symlink* or a regular *file name* depending on how it's specified.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref#_description):

> It follows **real** symlinks only if they start with "refs/": otherwise it
>   will just try to read them and update them as a regular file.

So that's why if you say `git update-ref master <value>` it will treat `master` as a file name and create it in the *.git* directory. By the same token, when you say `git update-ref HEAD <value>` it will write `<value>` to the `.git/HEAD` file.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, i understand that there are some special cases like HEAD or ORIG_HEAD. But apart from that: Shouldn't there be just 'standard' refs/? Why would i want to have a reference directly in my git root dir, or to make it concret, why would i want to have .git/someref instead of .git/refs/someref?

Comment: Well, `update-ref` doesn't have an opinion about what you should and shouldn't do with it. Being a low-level command, it simply allows you to manipulate Git's internal file system. Normally, you wouldn't create a branch reference in the _.git_ directory but other kinds or references like [`HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#The-HEAD) do exist there and you should be able to update them as well.

Comment: True, but (as of git 2.41) plumbing is inconsistently _sometimes_ opinionated: `update-ref main` happily creates .git/main, `rev-parse main` then complains `warning: refname 'main' is ambiguous.`, yet `show-ref main` won't mention it and same command in delete mode `update-ref -d main` fails `error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'main'` cause it [isn't all-caps](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html%23def_pathspec#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpseudorefapseudoref).

Comment: oh, under a worktree there is also difference in where it puts it :-\  `git update-ref MAIN` puts it in the git-dir `.git/worktrees/mytree2/MAIN`, while `git update-ref main` puts it in git-common-dir `.git/main`.

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) improves git update-ref robustness, because "`git update-ref A B`" is supposed to ensure that ref `A` does not yet exist when `B` is a NULL OID, but this check was not done correctly for pseudo-refs outside refs/ hierarchy, e.g. `MERGE_HEAD`.

See [commit db0210d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db0210d445963e5d85f98e48d6a93b971779d449), [commit 65eb8fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65eb8fc344205a4039b989f07367f345101bbf28), [commit c0bdd65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0bdd658bd2f06dc1c0d8fd578e80831f8d53b43) (10 May 2018) by [Martin Ågren (``)](https://github.com/).
Helped-by: Rafael Ascensão rafa.almas@gmail.com.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 26597cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26597cb0cceb82b315c543f1cc02bbb72c537eaa), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> ### refs: handle zero oid for pseudorefs

> According to the documentation, it is possible to "specify 40 '0' or an empty string as `<oldvalue>` to make sure that the ref you are creating does not exist."
> But in the code for pseudorefs, we do not implement this, as demonstrated by the failing tests added in the [previous commit](http://65eb8fc344205a4039b989f07367f345101bbf28).
> If we fail to read the old ref, we immediately die. But a failure to
> read would actually be a good thing if we have been given the zero oid.
>
> With the zero oid, allow -- and even require -- the ref-reading to fail.
> This implements the "`make sure that the ref ... does not exist`" part of
> the documentation and fixes both failing tests from the previous commit.
>
> Since we have a `strbuf err` for collecting errors, let's use it and
> signal an error to the caller instead of dying hard.

---

Note: as explained in "[Does git lock a remote for writing when a user pushes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52668468/6309)"

> some references are considered "pseudorefs".
> These are never packed.
> The pseudorefs are things like `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, and so on.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), starts preliminary changes to refs API, which does influence those non refs references.

See [commit 55dd8b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55dd8b9108679da122d2c69fda3b9413651af4d7), [commit 0974341](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09743417a201511888aee42480e468ebf47fcecb) (27 Jul 2020), and [commit 0b7de6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b7de6c6835051a92ae3e2ff306583f5780c7ae1) (16 Jul 2020) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 95c687b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c687bf85b1922cc4b8c441cd8aeb4048977001), 17 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pseudorefs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09743417a201511888aee42480e468ebf47fcecb):Modify pseudo refs through ref backend storage
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> The previous behavior was introduced in [commit 74ec19d4be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74ec19d4be76c52b872e6f95b39ecbfbe5d9100c) ("pseudorefs: create and use pseudoref update and delete functions", Jul 31, 2015, Git v2.6.0-rc0), with the justification "**alternate ref backends still need to store pseudorefs in `GIT_DIR**"`.
>
> Refs such as `REBASE_HEAD` are read through the ref backend.
> This can only work consistently if they are written through the ref backend as well. Tooling that works directly on files under `.git` should be updated to use commands to read refs instead.
>
> The following behaviors change:
>
> - Updates to pseudorefs (eg.  `ORIG_HEAD)` with `core.logAllRefUpdates=always` will create reflogs for the pseudoref.
> - non-HEAD pseudoref symrefs are also dereferenced on deletion.

`git update-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/09743417a201511888aee42480e468ebf47fcecb/Documentation/git-update-ref.txt#L151-L157):

> If config parameter "`core.logAllRefUpdates`" is true and the ref is:
>
> - one under "`refs/heads/`", "`refs/remotes/`", "`refs/notes/`", or
> - a pseudoref like `HEAD` or `ORIG_HEAD`; or
> - the file "`$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`" exists
>
> then
> `git update-ref` will append a line to the log file
> "`$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`" (dereferencing all symbolic refs before creating
> the log name) describing the change in ref value.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), adjust sample hooks for hash algorithm other than SHA-1.

See [commit d8d3d63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8d3d632f4165955da49032d50279c20cfbde2e5), [commit 8c7e505](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c7e5059506c6840bfbd4dd8d1730784a5689719), [commit 6a117da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a117da6e523a82115733682f4d3f59755897d5a) (23 Sep 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9f489ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f489ac6bbb755fa4c83289e44cad12f3b765d69), 29 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`hooks--update.sample`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8d3d632f4165955da49032d50279c20cfbde2e5): use hash-agnostic zero OID
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> The update sample hook has the zero OID hardcoded as 40 zeros.
>
> However, with the introduction of SHA-256 support, this assumption no longer holds true.
> Replace the hardcoded $z40 with a call to
>
> ```
> git hash-object --stdin </dev/null | tr '[0-9a-f]' '0'
> ```
>
> so the sample hook becomes hash-agnostic.